# How to format to datetime from custom string?

Tags: c#, datetime

cb_date, cb_hour and cb_minute are comboboxes with string collections

```
 DateTime Time =  Convert.ToDateTime(Convert.ToDateTime(cb_date.SelectedItem).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"))
                 .AddHours(Convert.ToInt32(cb_hour.SelectedItem))
                 .AddMinutes(Convert.ToInt32(cb_minute.SelectedItem));
```

my code here gives format exception on the line

```
Convert.ToDateTime(cb_date.SelectedItem)
```

the text in cb_date is

**13-06-14**

Comment: What is your `CurrentCulture`?

Comment: Instead of `ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")` you don't need to convert it back to string at all. Just use the `Date` property of the `DateTime` to truncate the time, then use `AddHours` + `AddMinutes`.

Comment: Convert.ToDateTime(cb_date.SelectedItem.ToString())
                    .AddHours(Convert.ToInt32(cb_hour.SelectedItem))
                .AddMinutes(Convert.ToInt32(cb_minute.SelectedItem));

Comment: i changed it to this, but it doesn't solve my problem, because it throws an exception when i try to convert my string to DateTime..how to solve that?

Comment: @ClayCarmine Please tell us what is your `CurrentCulture` exactly.

Comment: current culture is en-US

Answer (score 1):

[`SelectedItem` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns `object`, that's why [`Convert.ToDateTime(object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ky38w316%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method invoked by the way.

But you said `Convert.ToDateTime(cb_date.SelectedItem.ToString())` still throws exception.

[`Convert.ToDateTime(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhz1w05e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method uses [`DateTime.Parse(string, IFormatProvider)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kc8s65zs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) explicitly. Here how it's [impelemented](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs#fce604498e2f810b):

```
public static DateTime ToDateTime(String value)
{
     if (value == null)
         return new DateTime(0);
     return DateTime.Parse(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
}
```

`DateTime.Parse` parses your string if it has a standard pattern of your `en-US` culture. And looks like `dd-MM-yy` is not a standard date and time format. You can check yourself.

Here an example on [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/);

```
foreach(var format in CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US").
                      DateTimeFormat.GetAllDateTimePatterns())
{
    format.Dump();
}
```

For .NET Framework 4.5, this prints;

```
M/d/yyyy
M/d/yy
MM/dd/yy
MM/dd/yyyy
yy/MM/dd
yyyy-MM-dd
dd-MMM-yy
dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy
MMMM dd, yyyy
dddd, dd MMMM, yyyy
dd MMMM, yyyy
dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm tt
dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm tt
dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy H:mm
dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm
MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm tt
MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm tt
MMMM dd, yyyy H:mm
MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm
dddd, dd MMMM, yyyy h:mm tt
dddd, dd MMMM, yyyy hh:mm tt
dddd, dd MMMM, yyyy H:mm
dddd, dd MMMM, yyyy HH:mm
dd MMMM, yyyy h:mm tt
dd MMMM, yyyy hh:mm tt
dd MMMM, yyyy H:mm
dd MMMM, yyyy HH:mm
dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss tt
dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss tt
dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy H:mm:ss
dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss
MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss tt
MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss tt
MMMM dd, yyyy H:mm:ss
MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss
dddd, dd MMMM, yyyy h:mm:ss tt
dddd, dd MMMM, yyyy hh:mm:ss tt
dddd, dd MMMM, yyyy H:mm:ss
dddd, dd MMMM, yyyy HH:mm:ss
dd MMMM, yyyy h:mm:ss tt
dd MMMM, yyyy hh:mm:ss tt
dd MMMM, yyyy H:mm:ss
dd MMMM, yyyy HH:mm:ss
M/d/yyyy h:mm tt
M/d/yyyy hh:mm tt
M/d/yyyy H:mm
M/d/yyyy HH:mm
M/d/yy h:mm tt
M/d/yy hh:mm tt
M/d/yy H:mm
M/d/yy HH:mm
MM/dd/yy h:mm tt
MM/dd/yy hh:mm tt
MM/dd/yy H:mm
MM/dd/yy HH:mm
MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt
MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt
MM/dd/yyyy H:mm
MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm
yy/MM/dd h:mm tt
yy/MM/dd hh:mm tt
yy/MM/dd H:mm
yy/MM/dd HH:mm
yyyy-MM-dd h:mm tt
yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm tt
yyyy-MM-dd H:mm
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm
dd-MMM-yy h:mm tt
dd-MMM-yy hh:mm tt
dd-MMM-yy H:mm
dd-MMM-yy HH:mm
M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt
M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt
M/d/yyyy H:mm:ss
M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss
M/d/yy h:mm:ss tt
M/d/yy hh:mm:ss tt
M/d/yy H:mm:ss
M/d/yy HH:mm:ss
MM/dd/yy h:mm:ss tt
MM/dd/yy hh:mm:ss tt
MM/dd/yy H:mm:ss
MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss
MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt
MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt
MM/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss
MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss
yy/MM/dd h:mm:ss tt
yy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss tt
yy/MM/dd H:mm:ss
yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss
yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss tt
yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt
yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
dd-MMM-yy h:mm:ss tt
dd-MMM-yy hh:mm:ss tt
dd-MMM-yy H:mm:ss
dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss
MMMM dd
MMMM dd
yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fffffffK
yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fffffffK
ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT'
ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT'
yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss
h:mm tt
hh:mm tt
H:mm
HH:mm
h:mm:ss tt
hh:mm:ss tt
H:mm:ss
HH:mm:ss
yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss'Z'
dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss tt
dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss tt
dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy H:mm:ss
dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss
MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss tt
MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss tt
MMMM dd, yyyy H:mm:ss
MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss
dddd, dd MMMM, yyyy h:mm:ss tt
dddd, dd MMMM, yyyy hh:mm:ss tt
dddd, dd MMMM, yyyy H:mm:ss
dddd, dd MMMM, yyyy HH:mm:ss
dd MMMM, yyyy h:mm:ss tt
dd MMMM, yyyy hh:mm:ss tt
dd MMMM, yyyy H:mm:ss
dd MMMM, yyyy HH:mm:ss
MMMM, yyyy
MMMM, yyyy
```

As you can see, `en-US` culture doesn't have a standard pattern as `dd-MM-yy`.

You can use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods for parsing custom date and time strings.

```
string s = "13-06-14";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "dd-MM-yy", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"),
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    dt.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy").Dump();
}
```

Output will be;

```
13-06-2014
```

Here a <kbd>[**`demonstration`**](http://ideone.com/28kkyR)</kbd>.